# I have a code that show the barcode image but it will show only the image once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working to show the bar codes generated and stored in date base. Right now i am able to get the bar code number from data base and show the image in HTML using code39.js. My code is billow it will show the image once only i want to show all the image and then download the label for products.

```
<div class="panel panel-info ">
<div class="panel panel-heading">
    Bar Codes
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">

    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var items in Model.BarCodeItems)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @for (int i = 0; i <= @items.Quantity;i++ )
                {
                <div id="externalbox" style="width:4in">
                    <div id="inputdata">@items.BarCode</div>
                </div>
                <br />
                }   
            </td>
            <td>
                @items.Name
                @items.Quantity
            </td>

        </tr>

    }
</table></div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  function get_object(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
  }
get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,8);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ids, and it must be unique. Try to use class, like this:

```
<div class="externalbox" style="width:4in">
    <div class="inputdata">@items.BarCode</div>
</div>
```

And in your script:

```
 $('.inputdata).each(function() {
    var code = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(DrawCode39Barcode(code,8));
 });
```

If you don't want to use jQuery:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inputdata");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var code = x[i].innerHtml;
    x[i].innerHtml = DrawCode39Barcode(code,8);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please, make the post as the correct answer to help other people.